# Making best use of Objective-C dynamic features

Tags: objective-c

I have been using Objective-C for a little while but being from a static type background (C#) I think I am using it in a very static way. Declaring objects as id feels alien to me and I can't see what the benefits are. Can anyone shine a light for me to get a better understanding of this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Objective-C is kind of a hybrid language, in which you can be as dynamic and as static as you want. You can declare all the types of all the variables if you want, you can even declare delegate variables as NSObject<Protocol>* if you want. **The id type works less as a real type and more like a hint to the compiler** telling him "hey, I know what I'm doing, just trust me on this", making the compiler avoid any type checking on that particular variable.

The first obvious benefit of the Objective-C type system is that container types (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet) accept and return id types. This removes the need for templates and generics altogether (like in C++, Java and C#).

Even better, you can actually have containers with elements of any kind inside. As long as you know what goes inside, nobody will complain if you add two NSStrings, one NSNumber and an NSValue inside the same NSArray. You can do that in other languages, but you have to use the "Object" base class, or the void* type, and then you require to box and unbox (or cast up and down) variables in order to get the same behaviour. In Objective-C you just assign, which removes the noise generated by casting operators and boxing operations. Then you can ask "respondsToSelector:" or "class" to each object, in order to know the identity and the operations you can perform with them, at runtime. In Objective-C, reflection is a first class citizen.

Another benefit is the reduced compilation times; the compilation of an Objective-C program is in general much faster than its equivalent in C++, given that there aren't that many type checks performed, and much linking is done at runtime. The compiler trusts more the programmer.

Finally, Objective-C's dynamic type system makes possible to have a tool like Interface Builder. This is the main reason why Cocoa and Cocoa Touch has faster development times; the GUI can generate code with "id" types all over the place, and this is deserialized whenever the NIB is loaded in memory. The only language that comes close to Objective-C in terms of UI design experience is C# (and VB.NET, of course) but at the price of a much heavier application.

I personally prefer to work with a more static type checking, and I even turn on the "Treat Warnings as Errors" setting in the Objective-C compiler; I've written a blog post about it:

http://akosma.com/2009/07/16/objective-c-compiler-warnings/

This is particularly useful when you are working with developers who are new to the language. It makes the compiler whine more often than usual :)

Static type system pundits might disagree with all these points, arguing that static type checking allows for "intellisense" IDEs and better maintenance in general. I worked using .NET for years (2001 - 2006) and I must say that dynamic languages tend to produce less code, are easier to read, and in general, gives more freedom to work. The tradeoff (there's always a tradeoff) is that there is less information at compile time. But as I tend to say, **compilers are a poor man's suite of tests.** The best thing IMHO is to have a good suite of tests, and a good bunch of human testers torturing your code to find bugs, no matter what language you choose.

Comment: Thanks @akosma for take the time to write this excelent answer. :D

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C's dynamism shines not just in the fact that every object is an `id`. Rather, it shines in the power of the Objective-C runtime and the ease to use it. A few examples of clever uses of runtime by Apple itself:

[DO](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html) allows you to set up an proxy object for an Obj-C object in a separate app / separate machine. This is done by intercepting all the message sent to the proxy object, packing it up, sending it to the other app, and invoking it there.

[KVO](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/index.html) is implemented by dynamically replacing the setter method so that it automatically notifies the observers. (Well it's in fact subtler than that...)

[CoreData accessors](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html) are generated at run time for each subclass of `NSManagedObject`, etc.

And, you can use the [runtime](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide) from your code, too. I once used it for a good effect, mimicking CoreData and generating accessors at the run time, and having only their declaration in the header file. Thus you can get the merit of both the static typing (compile time error from the declaration in the header) and the dynamism (runtime generation of methods).

Mike Ash has written an excellent series of blog posts on how the runtime works and how to use it effectively. You just have to read it! [DO](http://mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-02-20-the-good-and-bad-of-distributed-objects.html), [KVO](http://mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html), [message forwarding](http://mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-27-objective-c-message-forwarding.html) and more. There are also many other interesting posts on the net, like [fun with kvc](http://kickingbear.com/blog/archives/9) and higher-order messaging [1](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HigherOrderMessaging), [2](http://www.metaobject.com/papers/Higher_Order_Messaging_OOPSLA_2005.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

It’s actually rather rare that you would need to declare an object as type `id`, as you should generally know what type you are expecting. Sometimes you might use an `id<Protocol>` type, if you don’t know the actual type of an object but know that it should conform to a specific protocol.

Is there a particular scenario you are thinking of?

Comment: I am using id<Protocol> but that feels strongly typed to me and is analogous to using interfaces in c#. I have seen people mention that some tasks become trivial in dynamic languages but they never gave any examples. I guess I just want to make sure I am getting the full benefit of the language and not making things harder for myself by thinking strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

Passing instance as `id` is common when designing action's method; connecting a button to a method, the target looks like `doSomething:(id) sender;`.

In this case, it allows different kind of controls to use the same action's method, without prior knowledge of what these controls will be. In the action's method code, you can test for the class of the sender or simply use its `tag` property, to decide what to do.

```
-(void) doSomething:(id) sender {
    // Get the sender's tag whatever it is
    int tag = [sender tag]; 
    switch(tag) {
        case 1:
            // ...
            break;
        case 2:
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```